# Temporary hiding of fields

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to hide the fields which are not in use ?

For example consider

```
id: <input type="text" name="id"/>
<p>title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
<p>name:<input type="text" name="rno"/></p>
<p>age:<input type="text" name="age"/></p>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info"/>
```

In the above field i just want to display id field initially ..when user submits the id  based on the id the other fields like title,name, age needs to be displayed.

Is there a way i can do it?

I am not looking for permanent hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give more details in order to give you right solution, but if you are just tying to show items than you can do it this way

```
id: <input type="text" name="id"/>
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
<p>title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
<p>name:<input type="text" name="rno"/></p>
<p>age:<input type="text" name="age"/></p>
</div>
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info" onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="I'm hidden!" />
```

When the form has been submitted, you can simply change "hidden" to the desired type.

Comment: If you're only using the form for display purposes then you might consider using CSS to change the visibility (display property) as @Senad suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the following css property to make an element hidden:

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you have to do is apply a class to a container div that hides the desired elements and then utilize jQuery to display the div when the id input box changes:

CSS:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
id: <input type="text" name="id"/>
<div class="hidden">
    <p>title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
    <p>name:<input type="text" name="rno"/></p>
    <p>age:<input type="text" name="age"/></p>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info"/> 
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("input").change(function(){
    $(".hidden").removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To just manipulate visibility you could use jQuery methods:

```
$('your selector').show()
$('your selector').hide()
```

If you are submitting the form then the following might be useful:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    id: <input type="text" name="id"/>

    <?php
    if ($_POST['id'] != '') {
    ?>
    <p>title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
    <p>name:<input type="text" name="rno"/></p>
    <p>age:<input type="text" name="age"/></p>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>

    <input type="submit" id="button1" value ="Get Info"/>
</form>
```

This will **only** display other fields if anything was entered in *id*